avoid jest running in watch mode
when i use npm run test it run the jest in mode but i only want to run it once, is there a way to avoid the jest running in watch  mode by default
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "watch": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "test": "jest ",
    "test-watch": "jest --watch",
    "cluster": "pm2 start src/server.js -i max"
}

i did try to go through the docs but things aren’t much clear
thanks for helping

When you run npm run test it runs in watch mode? it should only run one time since you have already another script npm run test-watch to run it in watch mode.

Since the command does not have the watch in it, My only guess is that it is set in the jest.config.[json|js] file. Check if there is a watch option in it set to true and remove it.

i don’t have that file, first i try to make one and then set watch option to false and then i delete that one but neither worked for me

You can check the package.json because jest can have config there. jest by default does not run on watch mode. You need to check your project if their config that has watch. And maybe you can create a temp empty project to check if the config is set on project level on jest level
